# Upload SQL Server Reporting Services Report to CRM premises version

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

This might be the fundamental question on execution of ssrs reports.

I have requirement of runnins SSRS reports from CRM.

I have built SSRS reports in BIDS they are up and working in BIDS.

Now we have MS Dynamics CRM. we would like to upload this reports to CRM and run it from there.

So, for an example, if we go to CRM to specific client profile it will show all details related to him like FName, LName, Address etc.

Now All these fields which I can see on that page has in my SSRS reports plus more fields from different table to get complete detail report for that client.

So my basic question is I have created SSRS reports, how do I upload them to CRM and run it from there.?

Since I am confuse in asking any help would be great to clear confusion and eventually get to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the "Publish a report in Microsoft Dynamics CRM by using the web application" section [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn531093.aspx).

> 1. Create a new report or modify a report by using SQL Server Data Tools. More information: Create a new report using SQL Server Data
>      Tools
> 2. Sign in to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, and select Sales > Reports.
> 3. On the command bar, select New.
> 4. In the Report:New Report dialog box, in the Report Type list, select Existing File, select Browse, and then specify the location of
>      the .rdl file in the File Location box.
> 5. Specify appropriate data in the Details section of the Report:New Report dialog box.
> 6. Select Save and Close.
>
> You can test the report by selecting it from the Available Reports
>   list. To add the report to context-sensitive lists and forms in
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM follow the steps in Determine where the report
>   will appear.

Comment: Since it's we already did customization of CRM , I don't have sales but I went into my solution and then report and then added existing report. When I clicked on the run report it gave me following error " rsInvalidDataSourceReferences" . I belive it's somthing I need to change on my reports which I already developed in SSRS through SSDT

Comment: Dynamics CRM Online only supports Fetch-based reports.  If your data sources aren't fetch based, they won't work.  More info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531081.aspx), you'll need the CRM 2016 Report Authoring Extension. Are your data sources fetch?

Comment: Our is premises CRM, do you think that will make a difference?

Comment: If you're on premise, then you should be able to deploy reports that query the filtered views.  Unfortunately, I'm not really sure what your error could be about, then.  If you get completely stuck, you can always try recreating your report using the new Report Authoring Extension.  That would obviously suck, but it would probably work.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Let me get this right and please forgive me if you think if this is silly question! I have reports running in SSDT, My Datasource and CRM Database is same. DO you want me to install new report authoring extension and install in on machine where CRM is running.? And then I can give web page link back to reports server folder. right?